# Is using a tool named "Symantec Backup Exec / Veritas Backup Exec" a good appraoch to backup sharepoint application servers and its databases

Tags: 2013, 2016, backup, restore, disaster-recovery

I am reviewing our backup policy for sharepoint on-premises farms 2013 & 2016. where our IT admins mentioned that they backup all  Microsoft applications such as exchnage,sharepoint, sql server, etc.. using a tool named "Symantec Backup Exec / Veritas Backup Exec". now in our cases we have these 2 farms for 2 customers:-

1. Windows server 2008 R2 acting as sharepoint 2013 application server + another Windows 2008 R2 containing the databases.
2. Windows server 2012 R2 acting as sharepoint 2016 application server + another Windows 2008 R2 containing the databases.

**so can anyone advice if using the "Symantec Backup Exec/ Veritas Backup Exec" are supported tools for backuping sharepoint application servers? and their databases? and do those types of backups support disaster recovery scenarios?** for example in-case the whole sharepoint application server crashes? or the whole database server crashes? or both of them?

now for the sharepoint site backups, i already do a daily backups for the site collections using this command "Backup-SPSite ....", this backup allow me to restore certain site collections if we did a faulty settings or wrong critical update to the data.. but the backup using "Backup-SPSite" does not cover disaster recovery scenarios, as we can only restore the site collections on the same farm which have the same patches and updates, and will not cover backuping the managed services.. So can anyone advice if using the "Symantec Backup Exec" & "Veritas Backup Exec" are supported tools for backuping sharepoint application servers? and their databases?to cover disaster recovery scenarios?

Comment: You also want to backup the farm on a regular basis to help reduce downtime in case of failure. I would find out how often they are running backups and make sure they have snapshots that are easy to redeploy in case of system failure. I would have them run a backup and then try to recover it on another configuration...maybe use AWS for testing.

Comment: @jpollar now the `Symantec Backup Exec/ Veritas Backup Exec` is suppose to be a full backup solution and covers disaster recovery. Now i can run `Backup-SPFarm` to take a full backup for the farm,, but to be able to restore the farm i will need to build a sharepoint application server which have the same patches as the source, which the `Backup-SPFarm` will not do, as the `Backup-SPFarm` does not backup any thing about the hosting operating system such as the patches installed..

Comment: The key is to find out how often they're doing backups.

Comment: @jpollar the backup is been done daily after business hours..

Comment: Then you should be okay. You just need to make sure the backups can be restored in a timely fashion in case of disaster.

Comment: Veritas is what we use...and haven't any problems with it. just fyi

Comment: @jpollar Thanks for the reply... so it should cover scenarios such as disaster recovery , where the SP application server and/or sharepoint database server got crashed..

Comment: Correct...good luck